# Search TextField inside List looses focus when results are empty

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this basic setup:

```
struct TestView: View {
    let items = ["abc", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField("enter text", text: $text)
            let filtered = items.filter { text.isEmpty || $0.localizedStandardContains(text) }
            ForEach(filtered, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when typing a search text, while the results are shown it works fine. But as soon as there are no results left, the keyboard looses focus. Same issue when there was no result before and then a result shows up.

The `TextField` should stay inside the `List`. I could filter per item instead of doing the `let filtered = items.filter ...` which also solves it, but I can't do that in my actual code.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: demo gif]

Comment: try to not make the filtering inside the view, instead make filtering in a view model, and let view update the list based on a published property in the view model. We should not make any calculating inside the view body that refreshes the view again.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I tried that, as long as the `TextField` is inside the List it's still the same issue, even if both `items` and `items.filter` is happening inside an `@Observable class`

Comment: one thing you could try is to force keyboard to reappear on text change, but this will cause a glitch, as keyboard disappears first and reappear again, otherwise you should move it out of list, since list view needs to be refresh based on items it shows, and it seems to be ending the edit session